# How do I hide or fade out an image (created with loadImage)?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I have an image that I am rendering, using `loadImage`. How can I make it so when I press h on my keyboard, will hide the image? And how can I fade out the image?

Code:

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title>Image Testing</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```js
let img;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage('https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500')
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 300);
}

function draw() {
    background(225);
    fill(0);
    image(img, 0,0)
}
```

Comment: This is the first result in google for "p5 fade image" https://editor.p5js.org/remarkability/sketches/rtM08miUD

Comment: @AndyRay That is text, not an image. It doesn't work when I add an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest way I can think is using [`tint()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/tint).

Here's a basic demo: move the mouse horizontally to change transparency:

```js
let img;
let alpha = 255;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage('https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500')
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 300);
}

function draw() {
    alpha = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 255);
    background(225);
    fill(0);
    circle(mouseX, mouseY, 30);
    tint(255, alpha);
    image(img, 0,0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Remember you can isolate render styles (such as `tint()`) using [`push()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/push)/[`pop()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/pop)

Additionally, you can manually access [`p5.Image` pixel data](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.Image) and modify the alpha channel:

```js
let img;
let alpha = 255;
let imgFaded;

function preload() {
    img = loadImage('https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500')
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(500, 300);
    imageMode(CENTER);
    imgFaded = img.get();
}

function draw() {
    alpha = map(mouseX, 0, width, 0, 255);
    background(225);
    fill(0);
    circle(250, 150, 150);
    setImageAlpha(img, imgFaded, alpha);
    image(imgFaded, mouseX, mouseY);
}

function setImageAlpha(src, dst, alpha){
  alpha = constrain(alpha, 0, 255);
  src.loadPixels();
  dst.loadPixels();
  const NUM_BYTES = dst.pixels.length;
  // skip every 4 values (r, g, b, a)
  for(let i = 0 ; i < NUM_BYTES; i+= 4){
    // copy R, G, B
    dst.pixels[i + 0] = src.pixels[i + 0];
    dst.pixels[i + 1] = src.pixels[i + 1];
    dst.pixels[i + 2] = src.pixels[i + 2];
    // access alpha (index + 3) and modify
    dst.pixels[i + 3] = alpha;
  }
  dst.updatePixels();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.2.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I believe you're more than capable of doing that yourself. You need a few "ingredients": 1.create a global boolean variable to keep track wether the image should fade or not (`let isFading = false`). 2.   use `keyPressed()` (and check `if(key === 'h')` , if so, set the fading boolean to `true`).  3. in `draw()`, check if the fading boolean is `true`, and if it is, simply decrease the transparency value (e.g. `alpha--;`). You may also want to check if alpha is less than 0, if so, keep it at 0 (alternatively you can use [`constrain()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/constrain). Have fun!