# How can I make two images fade in and out by scrolling with p5?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
var f
var w

function setup() {
  imageMode(CENTER);
  createCanvas(848, 480);
  wall = loadImage('image/background.png')
  feng = loadImage('image/feng.png')
  wei = loadImage('image/wei.png')
  f = 255
  w = 0
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  image(wall, 424, 240);
  image(feng, 240, 240);
  image(wei, 668, 240)
}
```

I am just starting to use Javascript although I do not know anything about it.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean crossfade between images (e.g. fade in one image while the other one fades out), you can use [`map()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/map) the [`scrollX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollX) position for example to control the transparency of one image and compute the other image's transparency as the inverse value.

You can compute the inverse by subtracting from it's maximum value.

You can use [`tint()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/tint) to control transparency in p5.js

Let's break this down:

1. map scrollY from it's range `(0, windowHeight)` to a value you can use for transparency, let's say `(0, 255)`: `let fadeIn = map(scrollX, 0, windowWidth, 0, 255)` (based on the aspect ratio of your sketch I'm assuming scrolling on X axis, but you can apply the same logic with `scrollY`)
2. compute the inverse (fade out value): `let fadeOut = 255 - fadeIn`
3. Use `tint()` to crossfade: you can see a simple fade example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66165730/how-do-i-hide-or-fade-out-an-image-created-with-loadimage/66165864#66165864).

Here's a basic crossfade example based on your code:

```js
var f
var w
var feng;
var wei;
function preload(){
  feng = loadImage("https://images.pexels.com/photos/20790/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=848");
  wei = loadImage("https://images.pexels.com/photos/20787/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=848");
}

function setup() {
  imageMode(CENTER);
  createCanvas(848, 480);
  f = 255
  w = 0
}

function draw() {
  // compute fadeIn(f) by mapping scrollX
  f = map(scrollX, 0, windowWidth, 0, 255);
  // compute fadeOut(w) as inverse
  w = 255 - f;
  
  background(0);
  // use fade in / out values to tint
  tint(255, f);
  image(feng, 240, 240);
  tint(255, w);
  image(wei, 668, 240)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Remember to use [`preload()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/preload) to load assets (images/sounds/fonts/etc.) in p5.js